# How to fix navbar dropdown menu in css

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with the dropdown menu when I hover in services menu. [Here's the problem (on Codepen)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvJLdG)

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 800px;
}
a{
 font-family: 'Alegreya Sans Regular';
}

#navigation{
 height: 113px;
 width: 800px;
 background-color: #17384D;
}
.weblogo{
 margin-top: 34px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
nav{
 float: right;
 margin-top: 60px;
 margin-right: 60px; 
 

}

nav ul ul{
 display: none;

}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;

 }
nav ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 45px;

}
nav ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 list-style: none;
 color: #FAD46B;
 font-size: 1.3em;

}
.active{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #FF972C;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <img class="weblogo"src="weblogo.png"></img>

  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">services</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Add `position: absolute;` to your `nav ul li:hover > ul` selector.

Comment: whats the problem and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the dropdown menu in services is freaking out. I want to fix it with block submenu.

Comment: @Jdsfighter why the submenus is in inline display? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvJLdG

Comment: Because with it being inline, it shifts everything else over. When it shifts everything over, you're no longer hovering the original element. By setting the position to absolute, it doesn't shift the original elements.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to create sub menus is this

Replace your html with this

HTML

```
    <div id="navigation">
    <img class="weblogo"src="weblogo.png"></img>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a onClick="toggleNavPanel('panel')" >services</a>

                <div id="panel">
                  <div>
                 <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                </ul>
                  </div>
               </div>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And add this to your css

```
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 0;
  width: 100px;
  top: 120px;
  transition: height 0.3s linear 0s;
  overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Add this javascript also

```
    function toggleNavPanel(x) {
  var panel = document.getElementById(x), maxH="300px";
    if(panel.style.height == maxH) {
      panel.style.height = "0px";
  }else {
    panel.style.height = maxH;
  }
}
```

Also remove this from your css

```
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: you did not add javascript